# como puedo mandar un variable php por onclick para una funcion js

Tags: php, javascript, html5

quiero hacer una etiqueta img html como un boton que mande un value php a una funcion js para luego insertar en un array, si me prodrian ayudar les agradesco infinitamente

php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $cartaNombre = $row["Carta"];


    echo "<img  src='$cartaNombre' name='$cartaNombre' alt='no se encuentra' width='7%' class='cartas'  onclick='this.disabled = true; valor(this)'>";
}
```

js

```
   var ESEAadn = []; 
  function valor(element) {
   alert(element.getAttribute("name"));
   var value = element.getAttribute("name");
    ESEAadn.push(value);}
```

este es el codigo

Comment: No veo el código donde quieres hacer eso, si puedes publicarlo te ayudaremos.

Comment: disculpa no puse codigo, ya actualize la pregunta con el codigo, gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Deberías explicar mejor el problema. ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona? ¿Qué resultado buscas y qué estás obteniendo en su lugar?

Comment: El error que noto en principio es que`name="..."` tiene el valor de `src="..."`  lo que no me parece lógico, te recomiendo manejes el nombre que usas en tu base de datos `name="Carta"`

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que en ese `onclick (onclick='this.disabled = true; valor(this)')` quieres enviar el valor puedes embeber codigo `PHP` de la siguiente forma:

```
onclick="this.disabled = true; valor('<?php echo $variables_php ?>')"
```

O bien podrias darle un `ID` al elemento `img` y pasar ese `ID` como parametro al llamar la función valor dentro del `onclick` y despues mediante `document.getElementById` recolectar los datos que necesitas

Comment: gracias por responder, no entendi como pasas php, talves podrias poner un ejemplo en codigo de como pasar php. y de como recoger con getelement byid disculpa pero soy muy novato

Comment: gracias por molestarte parece que estamos cerca, pero en el momento  de hacer el push me sale este error       ESEAadn.push is not a function